# grid float breakpoint css example

Tags: css

I have created a three columns grid template with 33% width each. I was hoping if someone would be willing to show me how to set up css so when I minimize the screen to 750px, the template will become a two columns template with 50% width each.

Thanks.

Comment: please code (important)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `@media` queries, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    #column_container  {
      -webkit-column-count: 2;
      -moz-column-count: 2;   
      column-count: 2;        
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 751px) {
    #column_container  {
      -webkit-column-count: 3;
      -moz-column-count: 3;   
      column-count: 3;        
    }
}
```